# SQLiteError on Android: Can't find column

Tags: android, sqlite, runtime-error

I'm trying to implement a database to store information about users for an Android app.

Here is a string:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 

                 "CREATE TABLE "

                  + DATABASE_TABLE_USERS 
                  + "(" + KEY_ROW_ID 
                  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
                  + KEY_NAME

                  + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
                  + KEY_PASSWORD 
                  + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
                  + KEY_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 
                  + " INTEGER NOT NULL," 
                  + KEY_ZIP + " TEXT," 
                  + KEY_STREET + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

I use this string to call db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE) in the OnCreate method.

I think this is where the error is occurring:

```
            public boolean findPerson(String uid, String password) {
                String [] columns = new String [] {DB_Helper.KEY_NAME, DB_Helper.KEY_PASSWORD};
                Cursor c = database.query(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE_USERS, columns,"KEY_PASSWORD = ? AND KEY_NAME = ?",
                new String[] { password, uid },
                null,
                null,
                null);


                 if(!c.moveToFirst()){
                c.close();
               return false;
                  }
                 else c.close();

    return true;
}
```

I immediately get an exception that says I it cannot find the column KEY_PASSWORD.

Here is the log file:

> 02-25 21:20:56.426: D/MainActivity(2257): save button clicked
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.695: E/SQLiteLog(2257): (1) no such column:
>   KEY_PASSWORD
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.695: D/AndroidRuntime(2257): Shutting down VM
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.705: W/dalvikvm(2257): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at 
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   ... 11 more
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_PASSWORD
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id_name, id_password FROM
>   reg_users_table WHERE KEY_PASSWORD = ? AND KEY_NAME = ?
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   com.example.wheresmystuff.Model.DB.findPerson(DB.java:57)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   com.example.wheresmystuff.Presenter.Login_Presenter.validate(Login_Presenter.java:26)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   at
>   com.example.wheresmystuff.View.MainActivity.save(MainActivity.java:48)
>
> 02-25 21:20:56.775: E/AndroidRuntime(2257):   ... 14 more

Comment: Use: `KEY_PASSWORD + "= ? AND " + KEY_NAME + " = ?"` instead of `"KEY_PASSWORD = ? AND KEY_NAME = ?"`.

Answer (score 2):

KEY_PASSWORD is a java variable name, not necessarily actual SQL column name. Double check what actual SQL name you have

Comment: Since the error message also uses KEY_PASSWORD it is sane to assume it is called so.

Comment: @poitroae - that has nothing to do with the variable. That's merely a string he he passed into the query. His variable KEY_PASSWORD could be = "KEY_POOSSWERD" for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very self-explanatory. Your selection is looking for columns (`KEY_NAME` and `KEY_PASSWORD`) that do not exist in the table. The error even gave you the compiled SQL so you can see your mistake:

```
SELECT id_name, id_password FROM reg_users_table WHERE KEY_PASSWORD = ? AND KEY_NAME = ?
```

Change your selection to `KEY_PASSWORD + " = ? AND " + KEY_NAME + " = ?"`

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
Cursor c = database.query(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE_USERS, columns,DB_Helper.KEY_PASSWORD + "= ? AND " DB_Helper.KEY_NAME + "= ?"
```